# Unable to parse well formed JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

I issue a request to an API, and I'm able to parse the **success** response result `(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)`, but when I get a **failure** response ("bad request"), the seemingly well-formed JSON result cannot be parsed by `JObject.Parse()` or `JToken.Parse()`, they throw.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = "\"{\\\"error\\\":{\\\"detail\\\":\\\"java.lang.NullPointerException\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"Error occured while setting field 'caller_id' with value null\\\"},\\\"status\\\":\\\"failure\\\"}\"";

        var jObject = JObject.Parse(result);

        Console.WriteLine(jObject["error"]["message"]);
    }
}
```

The exception:

> Run-time exception (line 10): Error reading JObject from JsonReader.
>   Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '', line 1,
>   position 162.

Stack Trace:

> [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from
>   JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '',
>   line 1, position 162.]    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings
>   settings)    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json,
>   JsonLoadSettings settings)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json)    at Program.Main()
>   :line 10

The exception points to the very end of the string, but I can't figure out what's missing. https://jsonblob.com can parse it after I remove the backslashes, I got rid of the apostrophe's, I "cleaned it up" with string and regex replace, I turned into a char array and build it again, all to no avail.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have so many slashes in your string? I ran your code with this string `var result = "{\"error\":{\"detail\":\"java.lang.NullPointerException\",\"message\":\"Error occured while setting field 'caller_id' with value null\"},\"status\":\"failure\"}";` successfully.

Comment: That's what comes back from the request, I'm guessing C# escapes a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you provide is well-formed JSON.  It's what you get if you serialize some data to a JSON string *and then serialize that string to a JSON string*.  To get the data out of the original JSON string, you therefore have to parse it twice.

The following works for me:

```
        var jToken = JToken.Parse(result);
        var jObject = JObject.Parse((string)((JValue)jToken).Value);

        Console.WriteLine(jObject["error"]["message"]);
```

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed it in a million years, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I console write your json string which is:

```
var result = "\"{\\\"error\\\":{\\\"detail\\\":\\\"java.lang.NullPointerException\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"Error occured while setting field 'caller_id' with value null\\\"},\\\"status\\\":\\\"failure\\\"}\"";
```

it returns:

```
"{\"error\":{\"detail\":\"java.lang.NullPointerException\",\"message\":\"Error occured while setting field 'caller_id' with value null\"},\"status\":\"failure\"}"
```

Which is not a correct json string. Your json string has to be like below:

```
var result = "{\"error\":{\"detail\":\"java.lang.NullPointerException\",\"message\":\"Error occured while setting field 'caller_id' with value null\"},\"status\":\"failure\"}"
```

So that when you console write this statement you will see that it generates below string which is a correct formed json:

```
{"error":{"detail":"java.lang.NullPointerException","message":"Error occured while setting field 'caller_id' with value null"},"status":"failure"}
```